# An Imporper Integral

Tags: improper-integrals

I am to find out whether the following Improper Integral converges:

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{e^{x/4}}{x^3{ln}^5x}\,dx\quad$$

Things that I've tried:
Comparison with $$\frac{1}{x^3{ln}^5x}$$
Or with:(Which is impossible since it's not a "Decreasing" function)
$$\frac{e^{x/4}}{x^3}$$
Or:
$$\frac{{1}}{x}$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the limit of your integrand at $\infty$?

Comment: maybe this helps $x^3ln^5x<x^8$

Comment: Using the Nth term test, the limit of this integrand as x goes to infinity is infinity, because exponential functions grow much faster than polynomial or ln.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The integral is divergent since

$$ \frac{e^{x/4}}{x^3{\ln}^5x}\ge\frac 1 x\quad \text{for $x$ large enough}$$

Comment: The funny thing is, that I just made the same conclusion! Thank you for your help!